# How to solve error "This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback."

Tags: java, servlets

I was trying to add a servlet to my Maven project and when I run the application and access its URL it gives me this error.
I leave you the servlet code and the index.html.
When I access http://localhost:8090/ServletSaludo / I get the error This application has no explicit mapping for / error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. I don't see the fault, I think I have created it and done everything right.

```java
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet("/ServletSaludo")
public class ServletSaludo extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<HTML>");
        out.println("<HEAD><TITLE>Hola Mundo!</TITLE></HEAD>");
        out.println("<BODY>");
        String nombre = (String) request.getParameter("nombre");
        if (nombre != null) {
            out.println("Hola " + nombre + "<br>");
        }
        out.println("</BODY></HTML>");

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet( request,response );
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Servlets</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Contenido -->
<div class="container" id="contenedor-principal">
    <h2>Formulario GET Saludar</h2>
    <form action="ServletSaludo" method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre-get">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre-get">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Enviar</button>
    </form>
    <h2>Formulario POST</h2>
    <form action="ServletSaludo" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nombre-post">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre-post">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Enviar</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the application annotated with @ServletComponentScan?

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your application and it worked for me. Please see the folder structure on whether you've kept it correctly or not.

[image]

And one more thing, since you added a tag for Spring boot, you can use `@RestController` or `@Controller` to create endpoints for your project.

Comment: Thanks it was the folder structure :)